# Windows authentication on remote server over LDAP

Tags: iis, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have two servers. First one is a server with ASP app on it and the second one is an LDAP auth server. I need to login on app server over LDAP on the second server and I need to use windows auth (NTLM or Negotiate). As I know based on my research to login on the server using active directory domain from other server they must be in the same local network. This can be established by VPN. But the thing is that I can't use a VPN. Can it be established somehow? I'm currently trying to configure IIS to not identify my user on my current domain and serve the credentials to remote server over LDAP using .Net. Sorry if I have a wrong understanding about something, I'm still newbie in windows auth and AD. Correct me if I wrong in something.

I'm using ASP.NET Core RC2 and IISExpress 10 on my local machine and my target framework is 452 due to using some old modules.

On remote app server I'm using IIS 8.5